# Is it safe to put drinks near snake plants?

Tags: houseplants, indoors

I have a snake plant inside my room that is placed on a desk.
I heard that such a plant is toxic (if consumed).

So, I'm wondering if it is safe to place my cup of water beside it. The desk is rather small.
Do I have to worry about any toxic chemicals emanating from it that might go inside my water?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sansevieria is only toxic if eaten - and then you'll only get an upset stomach because it's not that poisonous. There's no danger from placing it near food or drink.

Answer (score 4):

My father as a child took a chomp out of a sansevieria, he described it as just tasting painfully, eye wateringly, stinging bad, he has since survived to be a 74 year old retired botanist...

If you don't notice it altering the taste of your drink I would think that you are well below the threshold of toxicity.